# Center a dialog

Tags: java, gxt

How can I really center a dialog in GXT?

I create it like this:

```
VoteDialogBox vdb = new VoteDialogBox(activeModelID);
Dialog dialogBox = vdb.createDialogBox();
dialogBox.center();
dialogBox.show();
```

When I call `.center()` the dialogs upper left corner is in center. I want the dialogs center to be in the center of the screen. Anybody knows how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dialogBox.center();
dialogBox.setPosition(dial.getAbsoluteLeft() + (dial.getOffsetWidth() / 2), dial.getAbsoluteTop() + (dial.getOffsetHeight() / 2));
```

The idea is to center it and then adjust the location manualy by substracting half of it's width and height form the coordinates. But there is a known issue with `getOffsetWidth()` and `getOffsetHeight()` where they always return 0 no matter the size of the widget. In that case if  your dialog has a static size just put in the actual numbers.